# Android - Not reading few lines from database

Tags: java, android, xml, database

Hi am new to android and would like some help. So in my app I am fetching data from an xml file on a server and storing it in a database. I manually checked the database and all went well. Now when I am trying to read the data from the `connectToDB()` method in ActivityTwo class I see no data on the screen but when I read the data from the `offlineDatabase()` in the same class, I see the data perfectly on the screen. I am completely baffled by this situation. Any help would be immensely appreciated. BTW: `connectToDB()` is called when the user is online and `offlineDatabase()` is called when the user is offline.

**ActivityTwo.java**

```
public class ActivityTwo  extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> eventsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private HandleXML handleXML;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events);
        if(netCheckPls() == false) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Internet Connection")
                    .setMessage("Not connected to the Internet!")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
            offlineDatabase();
        } else {
            connectToDB();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //eventsData.close();
    }

    public void offlineDatabase() {
        DBHelper dHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        eventsList = dHelper.getAllEvents();
        addMoreRows();
    }

    public void connectToDB() {
        handleXML = new HandleXML(this, "http://eamplesite/example.xml");
        handleXML.fetchXML();
        //while(handleXML.parsingComplete);
            //;
        eventsList = handleXML.arrayList();
        addMoreRows();
        //offlineDatabase();
    }

    public void addMoreRows() {
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
       for(int i = 0; i < eventsList.size(); i++) {
           TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
           TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           row.setLayoutParams(lp);
           TextView tv = new TextView(this);
           tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
           tv.setText((String)eventsList.get(i));
           row.addView(tv);
           tl.addView(row);
        }
    }

    public boolean netCheckPls() {
        Context ctx = this;
        ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        // Check if wifi or mobile network is available or not. If any of them is
        // available or connected then it will return true, otherwise false;
        return wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected();
    }
}
```

**HandleXML.java**

```
public class HandleXML extends Activity {

    private String title = "title";
    private String link = "link";
    private String description = "description";
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String urlString = null;
    private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
    public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;



    public HandleXML(Context context, String url){
        context.deleteDatabase("EventsDB.db");
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        this.urlString = url;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> arrayList() {
        return dbHelper.getAllEvents();
    }
    public String getTheTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public String getLink(){
        return link;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        String text=null;
        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType();
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name=myParser.getName();
                switch (event){
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = myParser.getText();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if(name.equals("title")){
                            title = text;
                            titles.add(text);
                        }
                        else if(name.equals("guid")){
                            link = text;
                            links.add(text);
                        }
                        else if(name.equals("description")){
                            description = text;
                            descriptions.add(text);
                        }
                        else{
                        }
                        break;
                }
                event = myParser.next();
            }
            parsingComplete = false;
            //dbHelper.insertEvents(title, description, link);
            addToDB();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addToDB() {
        for(int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
            dbHelper.insertEvents(titles.get(i), descriptions.get(i), links.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void fetchXML(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    myparser.setInput(stream, null);
                    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                    stream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

**DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EventsDB.db";
    public static final String EVENTS_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String EVENTS_DESCRIPTION = "decription";
    public static final String EVENTS_LINK = "link";
    public static final String EVENTS_TABLE_NAME = "events";
    public static final String EVENTS_COLUMN_NAME = "title";

    public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_STREET = "street";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_CITY = "place";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";

    private HashMap hp;

    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table events " +
                        "(id integer primary key, title text, description text, link text)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertEvents  (String title, String description, String link)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("title", title);
        contentValues.put("description", description);
        contentValues.put("link", link);

        db.insert("events", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }
    public Cursor getData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from events where id=" + id + "", null );
        return res;
    }
    public int numberOfRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, EVENTS_TABLE_NAME);
        return numRows;
    }
    public boolean updateEvents (Integer id, String title, String description, String link)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("title", title);
        contentValues.put("description", description);
        contentValues.put("link", link);
        db.update("events", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }

    /*public Integer deleteContact (Integer id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("contacts",
                "id = ? ",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }*/
    public ArrayList getAllEvents()
    {
        ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from events", null );
        res.moveToFirst();
        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EVENTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
}
```

**events.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical">



        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

FYI the reason I want to delete the database, when the user comes online, is that I want to prevent similar data being added to the database (which I found was happening). Again would greatly appreciate some light on this matter. Thank You!

Comment: Make your HandleXML class as Object class

Comment: ^ In other words don't extend Activity

Comment: @Karakuri didn't work

Comment: What Terril and I suggested is not an answer to the problem, it is a comment on improving your code. There is no reason HandleXML should extend Activity.

Comment: @Karakuri Thanks for the suggestions but I really need a solution or another way am practically at my wits end here

Comment: Is there anything else that interacts with your database at this time? The only thing I can think of is you're fetching XML asynchronously on some other thread, and meanwhile the main thread loads what's in the database (which may be empty?) before that background fetching/parsing/inserting completes.

Comment: @Karakuri No there is nothing else that is interacting with the database. But the database cannot be empty as the offline method works fine. In the database there are 11 elements in each field (id, title, link and description) which are in the events table of the database EventsDB.db. I also tried to return the titles arraylist from the HandleXML file but that returned empty as well. Could it be that the data is deleted when the  stream closes in the thread?

Comment: Well, I don't see any reason why that would happen. Perhaps try running with a debugger and some breakpoints to see if the same code is being executed

Comment: @Karakuri I found out that for some reason the data is deleted inside the fetchXML method in the HandleXML class but not in the run method of the thread. I can't figure out why?

Comment: probably the line `context.deleteDatabase("EventsDB.db");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HandleXML class is calling `context.deleteDatabase("EventsDB.db");` in its constructor.

Comment: but if I remove that how will I be able to delete the old databse?

Comment: You can do it after downloading the data and before inserting. You also don't have to delete that database, you can delete all rows from the table with SQLiteDatabase.delete(): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])